# Unable to access WCF service with Transport security and Certificate authentication

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service with Transport security and Certificate client authentication. I hosted this service on Windows Server 2012 (test Server). I installed both the server certificates and client certificates. The WCF service is hosted correctly and I am able to browse the service on the test server without any errors. But when I try to access/browse the service from my Development machine (Windows 7) I am getting the below error

Server Error
403-Forbidden: Access is Denied
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied

I installed the client certificate and root certificate (i.e. the certificate authority) on client machine. The certificate authority is installed in CurrentUSer & local Machine->Trusted Root Certification Authorities-->Certificates. The Client certificate is installed in CurrentUser & local Computer-->Personal-->Certificates.

I guess I installed all the client certificates correctly too.

On the Windows Server 2012 (test server), I made sure all the WCF related components are installed correctly in the Roles and Features section like Http activation etc.

I am not sure what else to check in order to get this to work. Please let me know if there are any suggestions which I can try...Thanks

Comment: You may want to share your binding configuration for the client on the Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for hours, I followed the below link which sets the registry to bypass the revocation check for the certificate and it started to work

http://www.windowstechupdates.com/403-forbidden-access-is-denied-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page-using-the-credentials-that-you-supplied/

All my server and client certificate installations and settings were correct.

I hope this will help somebody from wasting their time...